# How to make a 2D Gaussian Process using GPML (Matlab) for regression?

Tags: matlab, plot, regression, gaussian

I have an *Nx2* input matrix called **X**. I also have the output values **Y** which is a vector *Nx1*. I create some data to test as follows:

```
Xtest=linspace(x_min,x_max,n);
Ytest=linspace(y_min,y_max,n);
```

So, matrix **Z** is of *nx2* dimensions and is going to be used as my test points. I use the default tuning of the parameters found in the demo provided with the GPML lib which is as follows:

```
covfunc = {@covMaterniso, 3}; 
ell = 1/4; sf = 1; 
hyp.cov = log([ell; sf]);
likfunc = @likGauss; 
sn = 0.1;
hyp.lik = log(sn);
```

and then use the gp function:

```
[ymu ys2 fmu fs2] = gp(hyp, @infExact, [], covfunc, likfunc, x, y, z);
```

I expected ymu to be the predicted value for each testing value in z. When I plot this like this:

```
[L1,L2]=meshgrid(Xtest',Ytest');
[mu,~]=meshgrid(ymu,ymu);
surf(L1,L2,ymu);
```

I get a strange surface. i.e i get stripes of coloured area rather some Gaussian like structure which is expected. The data in **X** and **Y** are real life data.
[image: This is what I get from my code]

What I would expect:
[image: What I would expect]

Comment: can you upload a picture of the plot that you think is wrong? also, you don't have a mean function, so is your training data standardized to be approx standardized Gaussian? If you didn't,  your hyperparameter fitting could be completely messed up.

Comment: how can i upload a picture here? I think it should work without the mean function since my data are good enough when observed with the eye.

Comment: edit your post, and there's a button for picture, click and upload.

Comment: if your Y has a large non zero mean, or its scale is large comparing to the initial scale hyperparameter you specified, then optimization of hyperparameter could run into numerical issues. report the learned hyperparameters and I can tell you if it's reasonable.

Comment: can you see the picture now?

Comment: can you overlay your training data points as well? to see if the fit is actually reasonable. Right now, it looks like your function is not varying in one of the variables. It could be a simple bug or it could be the way your data is actually.

Comment: I plotted the points as well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using it wrong. Your z variable should be given by [L1(:),L2(:)]. Then what you should plot is:

```
surf(L1,L2,reshape(ymu,size(L1)));
```

Comment: Error using reshape
To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.

Error in spatialGP (line 63)
surf(L1,L2,reshape(ymu,size(L1)));

Comment: size(L1)=size(L2)=500x500 and size(ymu)=500x1

Comment: do I have to do this ([L1(:),L2(:)]) for X as well?

Comment: If you wrote z the way I told you to, then ymu would be 25000x1. X and y can be anything, but X has to have size Nx2 and y has to be Nx1, where N is the number of data points.