# How to correctly use scikit-learn's Gaussian Process for a 2D-inputs, 1D-output regression?

Tags: python, regression, gaussian

Prior to posting I did a lot of searches and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21320964/how-to-make-a-2d-gaussian-process-using-gpml-matlab-for-regression) which might be exactly my problem. However, I tried what is proposed in the answer but unfortunately this did not fix it, and I couldn't add a comment to request further explanation, as I am a new member here.

Anyway, I want to use the Gaussian Processes with scikit-learn in Python on a simple but real case to start (using the examples provided in scikit-learn's documentation). I have a 2D input set (8 couples of 2 parameters) called **X**. I have 8 corresponding outputs, gathered in the 1D-array **y**.

```
#  Inputs: 8 points 
X = np.array([[p1, q1],[p2, q2],[p3, q3],[p4, q4],[p5, q5],[p6, q6],[p7, q7],[p8, q8]])

# Observations: 8 couples
y = np.array([r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6,r7,r8])
```

I defined an input test space **x**:

```
# Input space
x1 = np.linspace(x1min, x1max) #p
x2 = np.linspace(x2min, x2max) #q
x = (np.array([x1, x2])).T
```

Then I instantiate the GP model, fit it to my training data **(X,y)**, and make the 1D prediction **y_pred** on my input space **x**:

```
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF, ConstantKernel as C

kernel = C(1.0, (1e-3, 1e3)) * RBF([5,5], (1e-2, 1e2))
gp = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel, n_restarts_optimizer=15)
gp.fit(X, y)
y_pred, MSE = gp.predict(x, return_std=True)
```

And then I make a 3D plot:

```
fig = pl.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
Xp, Yp = np.meshgrid(x1, x2)
Zp = np.reshape(y_pred,50)

surf = ax.plot_surface(Xp, Yp, Zp, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.jet,
linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
pl.show()
```

This is what I obtain:

[image: RBF[5,5]]

When I modify the kernel parameters I get something like this, similar to what the poster I mentioned above got:

[image: RBF[10,10]]

These plots don't even match the observation from the original training points (the lower response is obtained for [65.1,37] and the highest for [92.3,54]).

I am fairly new to GPs in 2D (also started Python not long ago) so I think I'm missing something here... Any answer would be helpful and greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I tried as well using GPy and pyGPs, but as they are slightly less documented than sklearn I did not go very far in 2D either. But if you think one of these might still be a better option for my problem, instead of scikit-learn, please let me know -and why! Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're using two features to predict a third. Rather than a 3D plot like `plot_surface`, it's usually clearer if you use a 2D plot that's able to show information about a third dimension, like `hist2d` or `pcolormesh`. Here's a complete example using data/code similar to that in the question:

```
from itertools import product
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF, ConstantKernel as C

X = np.array([[0,0],[2,0],[4,0],[6,0],[8,0],[10,0],[12,0],[14,0],[16,0],[0,2],
                    [2,2],[4,2],[6,2],[8,2],[10,2],[12,2],[14,2],[16,2]])

y = np.array([-54,-60,-62,-64,-66,-68,-70,-72,-74,-60,-62,-64,-66,
                    -68,-70,-72,-74,-76])

# Input space
x1 = np.linspace(X[:,0].min(), X[:,0].max()) #p
x2 = np.linspace(X[:,1].min(), X[:,1].max()) #q
x = (np.array([x1, x2])).T

kernel = C(1.0, (1e-3, 1e3)) * RBF([5,5], (1e-2, 1e2))
gp = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel, n_restarts_optimizer=15)

gp.fit(X, y)

x1x2 = np.array(list(product(x1, x2)))
y_pred, MSE = gp.predict(x1x2, return_std=True)

X0p, X1p = x1x2[:,0].reshape(50,50), x1x2[:,1].reshape(50,50)
Zp = np.reshape(y_pred,(50,50))

# alternative way to generate equivalent X0p, X1p, Zp
# X0p, X1p = np.meshgrid(x1, x2)
# Zp = [gp.predict([(X0p[i, j], X1p[i, j]) for i in range(X0p.shape[0])]) for j in range(X0p.shape[1])]
# Zp = np.array(Zp).T

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.pcolormesh(X0p, X1p, Zp)

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Kinda plain looking, but so was my example data. In general, you shouldn't expect to get particular interesting resulting with this few data points.

Also, if you do want the surface plot, you can just replace the `pcolormesh` line with what you originally had (more or less):

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')            
surf = ax.plot_surface(X0p, X1p, Zp, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap='jet', linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: In the above, you apply an RBF kernel with the same hyperparameter initialization (i.e. `[5,5]`) and range (i.e. `(1e-2, 1e2)`) yet there are two input features. Is there a way to specify only one input 1 goes into one kernel, and only input 2 goes into a second kernel with different hyperparameters?

Comment: Would this way of 2D-input and 1D-input also be applicable to the support- and relevance vector machines toolkits available here https://github.com/JamesRitchie/scikit-rvm ?

Answer (score 8):

I'm also fairly new using scikit-learn gaussian process. But after some effort, I managed to implement a 3-d gaussian process regression successfully. There are a lot of examples of 1-d regression but nothing on higher input dimensions.

Perhaps you could show the values that you are using.

I found that sometimes the format in which you send the inputs can produce some issues. Try formatting input X as:

```
X = np.array([param1, param2]).T
```

and format the output as:

```
gp.fit(X, y.reshape(-1,1))
```

Also, as I understood, the implementation assumes a mean function m=0. If the output you are trying to regress presents an average value which differs significantly from 0 you should normalize it (that will probably solve your problem). Standardizing the parameter space will help as well.